# Reduce .exe size. Exe compressor

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compression, exe

1. Why VS2010 puts this kind of information (function names) in Release mode to executable?
2. Can i get rid of all unused data/segments in exe file, re-link it, re-build it etc. with help of some third-party software that would "analyze" the existing .exe and rebuild it?
3. Can i compress .exe file to shrink its size by adding some decompressing-on-start binary code to it?

[image]

Comment: 3: check UPX. I don't know why your exe shows this, please add details on how you get this view (and prefer text inside question instead of linked pics)

Comment: To point 3 - yes, that's called "exe compressor" and there's a lot of such software around. Is QT linked statically or is it a separate DLL?

Comment: Rather than VS, it is more likely QT putting various flavors of runtime type information into the binary as string literals. VS just does what it has to do.

Comment: Roman R. is right. The strings you see are *not* unused! What you see is most likely the runtime data for Qt's Meta Object system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. As a matter of fact, it is not really VStudio that puts these details but the Qt libraries that your project statically consumes. Qt is well known to be "generous" as far as the size of libraries is concerned.
2. Yes, having these details helps to have an idea about the features of your software. (e.g. using Qt).
3. UPX is well-known and very performant as far as the compression and portability is concerned. But don't forget that UPX is a compression (and decompression) mechanism and NOT an encryption mechanism. To hide some exports table, etc...you might use a real compression and encryption package like [VMProtect](http://vmpsoft.com/)

Comment: 2. Well, can you suggest some software that could just remove "fingerprints" of known libraries?

Comment: "fingerprints" of libraries is always changed by whathever compressor (encryptor) you choose. Just make a try with UPX and you will see that the number and the names of the original (statically) imported libraries will be reduced and changed.

Comment: Will try UPX with win32 version of my executable. Now i build it for win64 and UPX doesn't support it (-;

Comment: other products like VMProtect are more powerfull, and support 64bit...but are not open sources and free like UPX.

Comment: You may also try BoxedApp (http://www.boxedapp.com/boxedapppacker/index.html). I think they also support 64bit.

Comment: Visual Studio produces .NET applications.  UPX does not support .NET applications.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your executable is tens of megabytes, I would not bother.

But to answer the question, I would do 3. using [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Visual Studio produces .NET applications.  UPX does not support .NET applications.